# Populate arraylist with different objects inherited from multiple classses

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, parent, children

I have class parent A with children B,C,D.
Now I have another class E which should have an arraylist containing objects from classes B, C, D.

I thought of class E should extend class A, but I do not know how to add different objects in that arraylist.

Comment: The fact that subclasses B/C/D exist is irrelevant. It sounds like you're confused about the difference between instances and subtypes.

Comment: Can you please explain me? Why are they irelevant since the objects I need to add in that arraylist are coming from them? I am new in Java and I am not clear at all

Answer (score 0):

Lets have the code like below

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {}

class C extends A {}

class D extends A {}
```

Your E class can have instance of list as below

```
class E {
      List<A> list;
   }
```

class B,C and E are sub class of A. So this list can hold all the subclass of A

You can assign

```
 List<A> allSubClass = Arrays.asList(new A(),new B(),new C());
```